# Block routing if form is dirty [ Angular 2 ]

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am blocked with this,
In Angular 2, I need to block any user click event, even browser refresh if the form in the page is **dirty**

Could you help me with ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [canDeactivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-deactivate-guard)

It allows you to block routing away. You would need a shared service where you update the forms dirty state so that the guard can access it.

Answer (score 5):

The angular docs cover this exact question:
https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes
I'd leave that as a comment but I lack the reputation to do so.

Comment: For those coming to this in 2021 or after, better try this link:
https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes