# Angular 2++ | NgForm: Form.Dirty is Always Dirty

Tags: forms, angular, validation, typescript, dirty-tracking

#### Determine if NgForm Looks *Exactly* As It Did Before *Any* User-Input

---

It seems that `form.dirty` doesn't redact its value after it has been changed, and `form.touched` seems to always be `false` no matter what: `dirty` is `touched`, and `touched` is [tetched](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tetched?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic).

template.html

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmission($event, {}, form)">
    ...
    <input
        #input
        type="text"
        [name]="item.title"
        [(ngModel)]="item.estimate"
        (ngModelChange)="handleEstimateChange(item, item.estimate, input, form)"
    />
    ...
</form>
```

component.ts

```
export class LeComponent {
    @Input('data') public data: any;
    public handleEstimateChange: Function;

    constructor(private $: Sandbox) {
        this.handleEstimateChange = $.debounce(this.handleEstimate.bind(this), (1000*0.2));
    }

    handleEstimate(item: any, estimate: number, input: HTMLInputElement, form: NgForm) {
        if (!estimate) delete item.esitmate;
        (this, item, estimate, input, form);
        // Why does form.dirty never change back to pristine again???
    }

}
```

In the TypeScript, I'm *debouncing* the `ngModelChange` handler to give Angular a chance to change the `form.dirty` value before I check it. This is because `ngModelChange` gets triggered before the `NgForm` object has been modified.

If `!estimate`, because `estimate === ""`, then set it back to its original value of `undefined`. In this case, the form should look *exactly* like it did before *any* user-input had occurred.

However, when I put a breakpoint on the line right above the comment and I output `form.dirty` to the `console`, **the NgForm never changes `dirty` back to `false`.**

**Is it possible to determine if the form looks *exactly* like it did before any user-input?**

Obviously, I can write my own *dirty* logic, but wouldn't that mean that `NgForm` is kind of useless? There's got to be something I'm missing, right? How could *dirty* not mean *dirty*?

I've taken a look at some other SO questions -- the first one being similar but definitely not the question I am asking. They are asking if this is *intentional* -- I don't care; I'd like to know how to accomplish the goal above.

Close, but no cigar:

[angular2 formcontrol stays dirty even if set to original value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022263/angular2-formcontrol-stays-dirty-even-if-set-to-original-value)

[Block routing if form is dirty [ Angular 2 ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091338/block-routing-if-form-is-dirty-angular-2)

[Angular 2 getting only the dirty values in a controlgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342444/angular-2-getting-only-the-dirty-values-in-a-controlgroup)

[How do I programmatically set an Angular 2 form control to dirty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844092/how-do-i-programmatically-set-an-angular-2-form-control-to-dirty)

[Angular 2.x/4.x & bootstrap: patchValue does not alter dirty flag. Possible bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813051/angular-2-x-4-x-bootstrap-patchvalue-does-not-alter-dirty-flag-possible-bug)

Comment: Example to clarify: if a form starts clean with an input value of 'something', and then the user edits it to be 'something else', and then hits undo (for instance) to bring the value back to 'something', are you expecting dirty to become true when the input is changed and then false when the value is put back to its original?

Comment: As the other sites referenced have said, "dirty" means edited ... even if you edit it back to the same value. The "dirty" processing does *not* track your form's original values so it does not know if the user put the same value back. Angular has *no* built in mechanism that keeps the state of your original data. If you need that functionality, you'll need to implement it yourself ... or use something like this: https://github.com/ngrx/store

Comment: Another option is to use reactive forms instead of template-driven forms. Then your data model is *not* changed by any changes that the user makes. Then you can compare the form values to your original data model to determine if the forms looks exactly like it did before editing.

Comment: @ConorMancone, thanks for the inquiry. That's precisely the goal.<br />
@DeborahK, I'm aware that Angular has a different notion of what `dirty` means, I happen to disagree to say that _edited_ is actually _touched_. I also will be steering clear of Reactive Forms as the word on Google Avenue states they'll be deprecated -- but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Cody Do you have the reference/link for that? I'm on the Angular doc team and have not heard anything like that about Reactive Forms.

Comment: @Cody I just checked with the developer of both forms modules and **NEITHER** are going away. Not sure where you heard that one is being deprecated but it is not true. Could you provide the link to where you saw that?

Comment: @DeborahK, that's great news. I didn't read it, though, a friend/colleague mentioned a fellow colleague at Google (I believe) stated this. I'll see if I can inquire from my colleague to see if such a statement is `pristine` or just plain old `dirty`.

Comment: I'd appreciate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With template-driven forms and a very flat data model, I implemented it like this:

```
private currentProduct: IProduct;
private originalProduct: IProduct;

get isDirty(): boolean {
    return JSON.stringify(this.originalProduct) !== JSON.stringify(this.currentProduct);
}

get product(): IProduct {
    return this.currentProduct;
}
set product(value: IProduct) {
    this.currentProduct = value;
    // Clone the object to retain a copy
    this.originalProduct = Object.assign({}, value);
}
```

But this only works for very simple cases.

As I mentioned in the comments, using reactive forms gives you more flexibility in managing your data model separate from your user entries.

Answer (score 0):

#### What Was Most Useful

---

template.html

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmission($event, {}, form)">
    ...
    <input
        #input
        type="text"
        [name]="item.title"
        [attr.name]="item.title"
        [(ngModel)]="item.estimate"
        (ngModelChange)="handleEstimateChange(item, item.estimate, input, form)"
    />
    ...
</form>
```

component.ts

```
export class LeComponent {
    @Input('data') public section: any;
    public handleEstimateChange: Function;

    private resetFormControl = (input: HTMLInputElement, form: NgForm) => {
        var name = input.name, control = form.controls[name];
        control.reset();
        // control.markAsPristine();
        // control.setValue(undefined);
        // control.updateValueAndValidity();
    };

    constructor(private $: Sandbox) {
        this.handleEstimateChange = $.debounce(this.handleEstimate.bind(this), (1000*0.2));
    }

    handleEstimate(item: any, estimate: number, input: HTMLInputElement, form: NgForm) {
        if (!estimate) this.resetFormControl(input, form);
        (this, item, estimate, input, form);
        // Why does form.dirty never change back to pristine again???
    }

}
```

> **Note**
>
> - `[attr.name]="..."` (template.html)
> - `resetFormControl`

Basically, simply `delete`ing the value was not enough because it was still present on the `FormControl` object (`form.controls`). To clear it properly, invoke `control.reset()` for the individual control -- this in-turn invokes `.markAsPristine()` which communicates to the parent `NgForm`. Also, `input.name` was empty as it was only represented by `ng-reflect-name` unless `[attr.name]` elucidated the same value -- `[name]` is really just there because its required by Angular.

Now, anytime an `<input />` value changes -- *and* its falsey -- we reset the input ensuring that if *all* are falsey, Angular will automatically handle the `NgForm`'s dirty-state correctly.